# Double conversion would solve it but there is not such a thing in C++, right?

Tags: c++

I have something like this...

```
void f(dclass b);

class dclass
{
    dclass(string s);
};

f("s");
```

This does not seem to work. In principle, it could with double conversion: `char* -> string -> dclass`

So there is no such a thing in C++. Or maybe some compilers support it... Do you know a language where it may be possible?

Comment: What do you think this is supposed to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: why not write a `dclass(const char *);`? I guess you could say that it would be possible in Java, because Java doesn't have a `char *`, all strings are just `String`...

Comment: Yes, I did that.. just wanted to know what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could, but this won't really work in languages with overloading. You turn an O(N) overload resolution into an O(N*M) overload resolution. In general, overloading is considered a more valuable language feature than multiple user-defined conversions.

Comment: @Aftershock: N=number of overloads, M=number of user-defined types; overload resolution would have to look at all of these to see if there's an available double-conversion.

Comment: Mike is right. Note that both N and M may include template instantiations (in C++), which really makes this expensive.

Answer (score 4):

There can be more than one conversions in one chain, but ***at most one user-defined conversion*** can be in the chain. In this case, both `const char*` -> `std::string`  and `std::string` -> `dclass` are user-defined conversions. To solve your issue, you will need to add an implicit constructor that takes a `const char*`. Of course if you've considered all the undesired effects of implicit constructors.

```
class dclass
{
    dclass(string s);
    dclass(const char* ps);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can call your function like so:

```
f(dclass("s"));
```